# Deconstructing Spark SQL Dataset<Row> back into its individual StructFields/columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Java 11 and Spark SQL 2.13:3.3.2 here. Please note: I'm using and interested in the Java API and would appreciate Java answers, but I can probably decipher Scala/Python-based answers and do the necessary Scala/Python-to-Java conversions if necessary. But Java would be appreciated!

---

I understand how to create a new `Dataset<Row>` with a specified schema:

```
Dataset<Row> dataFrame = sparkSession.emptyDataFrame();

List<StructField> structFields = getSomehow();

StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(structFields.toArray(StructField[]::new));
Dataset<Row> ds = sparkSession.createDataFrame(dataFrame.rdd(), schema);
```

What I'm trying to understand is: **how do I do the reverse of this?** How do I turn a `Dataset<Row>` back into a `List<StructField>` (its schema; columns)? I see the `ds.schema()` method, which returns a `StructType`, but not sure how to deconstruct that back into a list of individual columns/`StructFields`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you need to transform it to Java list:

```
ds.schema().toList()
```

Full code:

```
scala.collection.immutable.List<StructField> schemaList = ds.schema().toList();
```

Comment: As Homer Simpson would say, **doh!** Thank you!